# WiFi network not displaying in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.10

I'm having some problem with my WiFi networks...my WiFi networks are not displaying as it works sometimes(rarely) and doesn't display most of the time. I restart my network manager to see if that helps but that wont help. My network manager wont show any wireless networks. it's completely vanished. I'm using Ubuntu 16.10

I've got..

Acer Aspire with Intel® Core™ i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4 and inbuilt graphics of Intel® Haswell Mobile..

I've tried lots of solutions from the forum but wont work..

Previous the command below worked for me sometimes but not now...

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

rfkill list

- 0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN   Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no
- 1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth     Soft blocked: yes   Hard blocked: no

iwconfig

- lo        no wireless extensions.
- enp5s0f1  no wireless extensions.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: Try these commands:  `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`
 and `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: network-manager-gnome already installed but not working!

Comment: Add output of: `rfkill list` and `iwconfig`. in your question

Comment: ive added it now!